# If $\sin A$, $\sin B$, $\sin C$ are in AP, then $a$,$b$,$c$ are in

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If $\sin A$, $\sin B$, $\sin C$ are in AP, then $a$,$b$,$c$ are in..

$1$ AP, $2$.GP, $3$. HP, $4$.none
My attempt:
Let
$$\begin {align*}
\sin A&=x\\
A&=\sin^{-1} (x)\\
\sin B&=y\\
B&=\sin^{-1} (y)\\
\sin C&=z\\
C&=\sin^{-1} (z).
\end{align*}
$$
So, what's next?

Comment: Why not just look at a single example? As far as I’m concerned, mathematics is an experimental science.

Answer (score 1):

If sin = 0, 1/2, 1,
then angles = 0, $\pi/6, \pi/2$.

Therefore not 1
($\pi/2-\pi/6 \ne \pi/6-0$),
not 2
(can't have a zero term),
not 3
(can't have zero).

Therefore 4.

Note:
Same applies to cos,
with the angles being
$\pi/2, \pi/3, 0$.

Comment: I assume that the intent of the question was to have $A$, $B$, and $C$ be the angles opposite sides $a$, $b$, $c$ of a triangle, hence the capitalization. (This has the feature of making one of the first three answers correct... I think...)

Comment: A, B, C seems to be the angles of a triangle

Comment: If they are, then my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Use  [the low of sines](https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the%20law%20of%20sines&*) to prove 1) as the correct answer.

$2R =\frac a {\sin A}=\frac b {\sin B}$ then $2R = \frac a {\sin A}=\frac b {\sin A + x} = \frac {b-a} x$ therefore $b-a=2Rx$ where $x$ is the ratio of AP

Answer (score 0):

[Your answer as long as A+B+C = $\pi$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLnaq9aUpuw)

Answer (score -1):

We know $a/\sin A=b/\sin B=c/\sin C=2R$.
       So, by instruction $\sin A$, $\sin B$, $\sin C$ are in AP.
     So, $2\sin B=\sin A+\sin C$.
         Therefore $2b=a+c$.
       So $a$, $b$, $c$ are in also AP.